# When was Esri File Geodatabase API made available?

Tags: file-geodatabase-api

When was the Esri File Geodatabase API made available?

---

This question was originally asked to try and determine when the File Geodatabase API would be made available.

Comment: removed gis tag; it's "meta" for this site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: an update without the ESRI spin (maybe) http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2010/12/file-geodatabase-api-beta-january-2011.html

Comment: 20 Jan 2011 -- it is released! But it is not going to be an Open API. ESRI is retaining control of the intellectual property. But that was to be expected.

Comment: [ESRI Developer's Conference Video](http://video.esri.com/watch/1216/the-file-geodatabase-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Esri blog posting announced that the [Esri File Geodatabase API Is Now Available](http://www.esri.com/news/releases/11-2qtr/esri-file-geodatabase-api-is-now-available.html) on 3 June 2011.

It can be downloaded [here](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3).

Comment: Finally, but quite limited in Full Geodatabase capabilities - but a start. Only 4 years in the making... progress

Comment: Yeah atleast it can trace Relationship Classes, that was the big question mark I had. Topology and Network editing is not as big an issue for me as no way to specify how another application handles the business rules

Answer (score 6):

See [Inside Geodatabase: File Geodatabase API Details](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geodatabase/archive/2010/12/13/File-Geodatabase-API-details.aspx) blog post.

The are some key limitations, though. If I were to name the most important ones, it would probably be that editing classes participating in relationships is not fully supported, as well as editing data in geometric networks. Also, support for rasters is not included at all in the first version.

Some of the limitations mentioned in the blog post are understandable, but still, I am very disappointed that after so many years of waiting, ESRI still can't get it quite right.

The C++ API is now available at [ArcGIS Resource Center - File Geodatabase API](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api).

Comment: Derek Law at ESRI also announced availability to the ESRI forums  with a link to same resource center File Geodatabase API stub as above.  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/10489-FileGeodatabase-Documentation-and-tools?p=70553#post70553

Comment: Definitely strings attached to using the API--called a Beta and you're a registered licensee with restricted rights to distribute derivative applications that ESRI retains rights to. Much tighter control than the Jul 1998 "release" of the Shape File specification. But still it's progress.