# Looking for best practices for GIS file systems

Tags: layers, spatial-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Organization and tidiness issues - How do you deal with multiple copies of layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/organization-and-tidiness-issues-how-do-you-deal-with-multiple-copies-of-layers)

I'm trying to organize my GIS data in a file system. 
I work with DTED (0,1,2), raster images (geotiff, jpeg..), shapefiles, DEM.
I have to define a file system with a list of directories and a file name conventions.
The solution must be simple and clear.

Is there a standard?