# Batch converting Garmin GDB to GPX?

Tags: convert, gps, gpx, garmin

I need to convert a lot of garmin GDB files to GPX in order to convert it to another vector format. Is there any tools available can do a batch convert from garmin GDB files to GPX? Using MapSource allow only one file at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/).

garmin GDB format is supported (see [this page](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.4.2/fmt_gdb.html)). Something like that should work:

```
gpsbabel -i gdb -f file.gdb -o gpx
```

A short batch file to loop through and convert all files in a directory:

```
for %%f in (x:\garmin_data\*.gdb) do (
   gpsbabel -i gdb -f "%%f" -o gpx -F "x:\gpx_data\%%~nf.gpx"
   )
```

The first `-f` is the input file and the second is the output. See [here about the `%%~` syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Thank you, I tried and it's a good app, unfortunately the output is in one single file, I'm hoping each gdb get converted to each gpx.

Comment: @Zery - Sounds like you need to loop through your files one by one and call gpsbabel on each one as you go.

Comment: @Chad - thank you, why don't I think of that, in fact I can even do it from inside my MapInfo using MapBasic and then just look for another source how to convert gpx to mapinfo tab programatically. Thank you.

Comment: I added an example batch file to loop through files in a directory