# Can File Geodatabase API be Redistributed?

Tags: gdal, ogr, license, file-geodatabase-api

Esri's file geodatabase API can now be used with GDAL/OGR - [Link](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html) however each individual seems to have to login to Esri and download the API files individually. For example this is referenced in a blog post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230316151959/http://www.paolocorti.net/2012/01/10/gdal_19_released/) and in the [GDAL build notes](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB).

The license agreement before downloading the API shown by Esri is at: http://resources.arcgis.com/node/agreement/3193

Clause 47 states:

> 47. Licensee may develop and distribute software or web applications that use the Esri File Geodatabase API to Licensee's end users.

The best discussion about the license is at [Paul Ramsey's blog post](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2011/01/esri-fgdb-api-no-servers-need-apply.html) from January 2011. This finishes with a final update that:

> Update 4: Received email from Esri confirming that the final license
> will be reviewed to ensure there are no ambiguities and that it
> reflects their intent that the API be usable by any application in any
> application category and the derived product freely redistributable
> and royalty free. So to the extent that the current license has any
> ambiguity it shouldn't be considered a red flag that the final one
> will.

So has or when will the Esri API be available as part of GDAL downloads or installations, and when can we distribute application which include the API?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Having written the FileGDB GDAL driver, I am glad you like it :)

The answer is that yes, it can be distributed. In fact, the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) distribution already includes it.

I got the confirmation that the OSGeo4W was an approved usage through a personal e-mail exchange I had with ESRI.

Comment: +1 Can the file gdb API also be used in the context of a web service?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great work! So you need individual approval from ESRI for redistribution?

Comment: For the OSGeo4W case, I wanted to have it up asap so people could use it. So I e-mailed people at ESRI directly and the e-mail thread trickled to the right person. However, as far as I understand, they are revising the legal wording so it is more clear. The *intention* was for people to use it and include it. However, it is clear that the legal wording says otherwise. Sort of shows how things work in a large corporation :) It is a matter of time before it gets revised and updated appropriately.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall AFAIK from the e-mail thread I had, the intention is 'yes'. Nevertheless, the best course of action for non-osgeo4w usages is to post the question in the forum.

Comment: I just downloaded the setup [exe](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/setup.exe) and installed it. After running 'ogr2ogr --formats', I do not see FGDB support listed.

Comment: This isn't the OSGeo4W bug tracker. Report OSGeo4W issues at [trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). See [ticket #241](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/241) in particular.

Comment: I'm trying to correct this statement(The answer is that yes, it can be distributed. In fact, the OSGeo4W distribution already includes it.

I got the confirmation that the OSGeo4W was an approved usage through a personal e-mail exchange I had with ESRI.) to anyone who may stumble upon this post. Probably should have post this as a comment, not answer.