# Editing file geodatabase without using tools from Esri?

Tags: python, editing, file-geodatabase

I am looking for a tool (Python library etc.) that would allow me to edit a file geodatabase without Esri software?

It is possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) has [python bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py) and a [FileGDB driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html), but it requires the FileGDB API SDK from ESRI (not free, but AFAIK free of charge).

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18692

Answer (score 6):

You could utilize my Python wrapper for the File Geodatabase API.

Read about it here:
http://libjoe.blogspot.com/2014/02/python-wrapper-for-esri-file.html

I also started an open source project for it:
https://code.google.com/p/file-geodatabase-api-python-wrapper/

Comment: link not working

Answer (score 3):

As wrote before + The File Geodatabase must be created in ArcGIS 10(+). File GDB's created using ArcGIS 9.X are NOT supported.

Also it is possible with Qgis with the mentioned library - well I only opened the file, didn't try to edit - more here: [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis)

(I wanted to wrote this as comment to previous answer but I don't see any link "add comment")