# Can Geodatabase files from ArcMap be imported and used in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, arcpad

I'm looking into QGIS and am doing some tests, but one thing I need to be able to do is use geodatabase files from ArcMap and ArcPad.

Is that something that can be done and with relative ease?

Comment: One important distinction to know is whether you are using a `Personal GDB`, or a `File GDB`.  They are both supported in `QGIS`, but you access them differently.

Answer (score 2):

see [GDAL: ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB)](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html) and [Can ESRI's File Geodatabase API be Redistributed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/can-esris-file-geodatabase-api-be-redistributed)

On Mac OS X you MUST download and install the FileGDB API yourself ([How to get “.GDB” Esri File Geodatabase in QGIS for MAC OSX 10.6?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-in-qgis-for-mac-osx-10-6)), on Windows, the OSGeo4W distribution already includes it ([How to get “.GDB” (Esri File Geodatabase) support in Quantum GIS (osgeo4w - qgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis).

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ArcPAD AXF files (which are really only designed as a temporary mobile geodatabase) and want to view them your best bet is to use something like the [FME AXF plugin](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help../index.html#//00s10000013m000000) to convert the files into another format you can use to read in QGIS. This does mean that you will require FME though which may be an issue if your requirement is a low(er) cost solution.