# How to add feature class from ESRI personal geodatabase (.mdb) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

How do you add a feature class in a ESRI personal gdb in qgis. I understand this can be done through the option add vector layer and select geodatabase. But what after that ? It doesn't allow me to browse through .

Answer (score 5):

The personal geodatabase is a proprietary format so it always was hard to read with software other than ESRI. Things changed recently and the new version of the GDAL/OGR library (the one that QGIS -as many other software- uses to handle vector and raster data) has support (don't know yet how good) for the personal geodatabases. This new version (1.9) is already out, now you have to wait a little to have QGIS compiled against this GDAL/OGR version. As soon as GDAL/OGR 1.9 will show in the osgeo4w installer I'm almost sure that the QGIS available in the same installer will works with that GDAL version under the hood.

Comment: But then under personal geodatabase option why does it show ESRI over there in the current 1.7.3 version.

Comment: Personal geodatabases (filename.mdb) have been available to qgis since at least 2008. File geodatabase (dirname.gdb) access on the other hand is much more recent and not yet mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually add ESRI personal geodatabase in QGIS from the add data options in file directory and just change the file type to ESRI personal geodatabase.
[image]